# how to add url to string stored in list

Tags: 2013, list

I have functionality of sending mail when something is approved in list. I want to store message body in configuration list. The message body is like

```
Thanks for subscribing. This is your link  Please click to activate.
```

I have to replace the word link with actual link `"http://localhost/item.aspx?id=13"` in my code. What is good way of doing it?

Comment: Are you using/building a SharePoint Designer Workflow?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a calculated column, then use the `CONCATENATE` function to put together the string. Make sure that the calculated column is being returned as a number, though, for your link to work.

```
=CONCATENATE("<div>Thanks for subscribing. This is your <a href='http://localhost/item.aspx?id=",[ID],"'>link</a>. Please click to activate.</div>")
```

Comment: where to make this ?

Comment: You're trying to add this text/link in your list, right?

Comment: yes correct. I think i will not even put link in list. Just text "Thanks for subscribing. This is your link. " . Then i wish to modify this text "link" with url

Comment: Right. So add a new column; select Calculated for the column type. Paste the above code in the formula box, then edit the URL. At the bottom of the page, select "Number". The formula above will return as `Thanks for subscribing. Please click here to activate`, with the second sentence as a link to your URL.

Comment: did you saw my updated question?

Comment: Updated the answer to match your updated question.

Comment: Using the ID column in a calculated column doesn't work well or reliably

Comment: Maybe use workflow to populate a multi-line text field, then?

Comment: Please see updated question. I m not using any link to store in list